# Validation of an email address in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, email

I have created an edit form in my Laravel application form which accepts an email address. I have used Laravel validation on the server-side. It is validating the email address correctly when I pass a clearly invalid value like 'xxxxxx'.

But the problem is when I send an email address with only a top level domain and no dot like 'xxxxxx@yyyyyy', it accepts it as a valid email address.

How can I validate the email address to ensure it's using a proper domain?

Comment: Can you explore some code?

Comment: Show us how you validate email ? It should look like this:`$data= $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ]);` You have everything in docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-email

Comment: Related: *[Laravel Email Validation: be aware of how you validate](https://minuteoflaravel.com/validation/laravel-email-validation-be-aware-of-how-you-validate/)*

Comment: Dose it really solve the problem? Because I faced the similar issue my users were misspelling word ```gmail.com``` to ```gmsil.com```. but It still allowing it because ```gmsil.com``` is valid domain name. But if I try ```kjsadhfkjagkjhadgsfkjhg@gmsil.com``` any random string as email front and gmsil.comstill it is allowing it.

Answer (score 64):

With Laravel 7: you can use

```
'email' => 'email:rfc,dns'
```

Comment: It works for me but can you explain what it does? (:rfc,dns)

Comment: This is documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-email

Comment: it works, thanks I don't need to use regex to validate the .com

Answer (score 13):

You can  simply do:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'Email'=>'required|email'
    ]);
```

Comment: I had the same problem in Laravel 8.x. Above mentioned code does not work as per requirement. In short it go green even if you have (exampl@domain).

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
$this->validate($request, [            
  'email' => 'required|regex:/(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)/i',
]);
```

Comment: i change my answer

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What are the limits for it? What will it fail for? Email address validation by regular expressions is known to be very complex or even impossible. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58725867/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 5):

It is not a Laravel issue. That is technically a valid email address.

Notice that if you tell the browser to validate the email address, it will also pass.

But you can use package *[EmailValidator](https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator)* for validating email addresses.

At first, also check these: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-email

**Or,**

use the *checkdnsrr* function.

```
<?php

    $email = 'email@gmail.com';
    list($username, $domain) = explode('@', $email);

    if (checkdnsrr($domain, 'MX')) {
      echo "verified";
    }
    else {
      echo "failed";
    }
```

Comment: Note: MX records are not required to host a valid working email server. If the MX record does not exist, the @ A record will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel email validation and unique email insert database use for code:

`'email_address' => 'required|email|unique:customers,email_address'`

Comment: Re *"unique email insert database use for code"*: It is nearly incomprehensible. Can you [rephrase](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65245049/edit), please? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65245049/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 10:

Try doing:
'email' => ['required', 'email:rfc,dns'],

Laravel uses the rfc5322 standard for email validation, which is based on RFC 5322. This standard defines the syntax for email addresses and is widely followed in practice.

The dns option checks whether the domain of the email address has valid DNS (Domain Name System) records. This helps verify that the email address corresponds to an existing and properly configured domain on the internet.